# Where is the ID stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, log4net, elmah

I use both Elmah and Log4Net (with ADONetAppender), and they are great. However, I notice that both have a table ID key (incrementing number), which doesn't reset back to zero when I clear their logs. Where are they getting this ID value from? Also, is there any reason for log4net columns not to use a Primary Key for the ID value, or rather will I have trouble if I add one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is an `auto increment` directive on the `ID` field in the database, as this value doesn't reset to zero when you delete entries, only when truncanted (please correct me, I'm not sure about it). Try reseting the table in the database directly instead of using the logger infrastructure.

Comment: Hmmmm... Interesting. What is truncate vs. delete? I know delete as the ol' SQL function, but never heard of truncate.

Comment: deleting would be saying `delete from table`, which just clears the whole table, runtime would be O(n). I'm not quite sure how truncate works exactly, but I think you can imagine it as drop the whole table instead of deleting all records, then recreating it.

Comment: truncating is oftentimes more efficient as it doesn't log each deleted record to the transaction log

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server then you can reset an IDENTITY column seed using the [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) statement like so:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, RESEED, new_reseed_value )
```

For example, to reset the `ELMAH_Error` table's IDENTITY column to a value of 1 you would use:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( ELMAH_Error, RESEED, 1 )
```

Happy Programming!